# Getting variable data from one class to another

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I  have a game where you explore a house. There are keys and locked doors. Each room is a different class. Lets say in one class your in a room and you find a key. I want a variable that says that the key is in the inventory. Then in another class there is a room where I need to use the key and open the door. How do I get the variable that says you have that key to open a door that looks for that specific variable to be true and lets you through the door. Sorry if this sounds incoherent. I am extremely tired and am writing this before I go to bed. Thanks in advance for the responses. I am also fairly new at as3.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a class assignment, so I'll only hint at an answer. :-)

Presumably you have a house class that contains the room classes, and presumably that house class can pass objects between room classes.

As well, an inventory sounds like a good class to create.

Hopefully that puts you on the right track!

Comment: How do I get the data to move? I am not getting the data to go to the other class. I press a button and set it to one, but when I try to display the variable it says "null".

Answer (score 0):

You can fx give your room class a method to take keys, that returns the key (text string, a key object or whatever you want it to be). And removes the key from room. When calling this method the key is added to a list of keys in Inventory (either call it from inventory or give inventory a method to add key).

Then give your door class a unlock method, that as parameter take the keyring (list of all keys Inventory has), if the right one is in there the door set itself as unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like ideal solution would be to create a singleton class for the inventory (as it is will have only one instance which you want all the classes to be able to access).

All room classes could call the inventory -

```
_inventory = InventoryClass.getInstance()
```

You can check more on how to create singleton classes here - 
http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2006/07/as3_singletons.html